# Need to get a Idea to upload a pdf file to dynamicaly selected directory

Tags: php, html, wamp

I want a know easy method to upload a file to a target location that can be selected by user(Admin) before uploading a file . what is the dialog box or such selection method to use to select a particular target location in the server . There is a root directory .

In side the root directory there are folders called 
2011,2012,2013,2014 .

In each of these directories there are some many directories so on .

So i want to manually select one directory and upload a file into that directory . I knew the php code for upload a file into a predefined directory . Now i want to change that code for my purpose .

This is the code that i used :
And this is the code example that i used :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

And php code is

```
<?php
         $ndir = $_GET['file'];
         echo $ndir;

         $target_path = "uploads/";
         $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
         // Check if file already exists
         if (file_exists($target_path)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
           }
        else if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
         echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
        }
        else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
        ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, what is the question here? You specify some "foldername" value inside your POST request which uploads the file. Since you have to move the file from its temporary upload folder anyway you can also consider that additional value to determine the final folder where to store the file.

Comment: What im asking is , i have to upload some pdf files into different different directories . For that purpose i want to select a suitable directory to upload a file . So i am looking for a GUI based selection panel to select that target location . what is the method that i can use??

Comment: @Eeji I just wanted a idea . That's what i asked . I provided a code that i have written . I wanted to extend that code for my purpose

Comment: Looks like you're well on your way to trying something @RajpirathapSakthithasan. Once you do, if you have issues, you can come back here and ask about those issues.

Comment: I would use maybe a dropdown `<select>` box giving users a choice of where to store it, send that information on `POST` and go from there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes. i got stucked with this above problem.And i knew that im doing well on my way . but  I want a idea . Can you help give a idea :D .

Comment: As someone said earlier in the comments, "that's not what SO is for". I'm sure you have some good ideas, you just have to try them.

Comment: Use `isset()` against POST variables assigned and taken from the value of a `<select>` and `<option value="folder_1">Folder 1</option><option value="folder_2">Folder 2</option></select>` and use the appropriate conditional statement to choose which folder to upload in.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for your valuable idea. I will try it now :) :) . I thought to find any dialog box based file selection panel. But i will follow what u have said .Great

Comment: @RajpirathapSakthithasan You're welcome. I've written something up and have posted it below. You can base yourself on that. *Cheers*

Comment: Yes . that is fine .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Since I had a few minutes to spare:*

You can use a dropdown menu select while setting a name attribute with values set as folder names.

```
<select name="destination">
   <option value="folder_1">Folder 1</option>
   <option value="folder_2">Folder 2</option>
   <option value="folder_3">Folder 3</option>
</select>
```

Then concatenate the folder destination to the upload/target path variable:

```
if(isset($_POST['destination'])){
  $target_path = "uploads/";
  $target_folder = $_POST['destination'];
  $target_path = $target_path . $target_folder . "/" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] );
}
```

- *Type of thing.*

---

**EDIT**

This will scan your entire sub-folders starting from the starting path given.

**Nota:** You will need to fill in the rest for the uploading part.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">

    <select name="destination">

<?php 
/* ============== PATH NOTES ============== */
// Either use full path. Keep the trailing slash
// $yourStartingPath = "/var/user/you/httpdocs/uploads/";

// or use current folder from script's execution
$yourStartingPath = "./";

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($yourStartingPath, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD
);

foreach($iterator as $file) {
    if($file->isDir()) {

        echo '<option value="'.$file->getRealPath().'">' . $file->getFilename().'</option>';

    }
}

echo "</select>";

    if(isset($_POST['destination'])){

      $target_folder = $_POST['destination'];
      $target_path = $target_folder . "/" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] );

    }

echo "<br>";
/* You can comment out the echo $target_path; */
/* It's just for testing purposes to show you the folder */
echo $target_path;
echo "<br>";

?>

<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Comment: yes . this is fine . I also thought this way. But here the problem is , if there sub directories inside these directories(Nested directories ) then we have to change the path . That means we have to concatenate the  $target_folder variable . I tried to use SESSION variable to use that as a static variable . But not work well . What is the way you can suggest me without using session variable.

Comment: @RajpirathapSakthithasan Reload my answer and look near the bottom under **EDIT**.

Comment: -ii Thanks for your valuable help . You given what i exactly needed . yea .

Comment: @RajpirathapSakthithasan You're welcome. We can now mark it as being solved. *Cheers* - To tick the checkmark.